# How to rewrite language uri when asking for files from a subdirectory. Nginx Docker

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

I'm configuring my first web page with Nginx and I'm beggining to experiment with having the web in two available languages at the moment.

My main issue is that when I enter example.com/es/Inicio or example.com/en/Index the files that are asked there from the templates, such as images, are 404, the servers receives the uri as `GET /es/sp.svg` or `GET /en/gb.svg` when the result I want and can't find how to do it is to request it from / as in `GET /sp.svg` and `GET /gb.svg`.

Here is the config of my server.

```
server {
    listen       81;
    listen  [::]:81;
    server_name  exampleIP;

    charset UTF-8;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log warn;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log main;

    rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/PHP;

    index Inicio.php Index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    #**This is just a poor try of my own rewrite.**
    #location @remove-es {
            #rewrite ^/es(.*)$ $1 last;
            #rewrite ^/es/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
    #}

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index Inicio.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ^~ /es/ {
                try_files $uri/.php $uri.php $uri/ =404;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass app:9000;
                fastcgi_index Inicio.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params; 
    }

    location ^~ /en/ {
                try_files $uri/.php $uri.php $uri/ =404;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass app:9000;
                fastcgi_index Index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ \.css {
        root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/CSS;
        default_type text/css;
        add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
    }

    #**This is where I want the server to look at when handling this type of files**
    location ~ \.(png|jpg|svg|ico) {
    root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/media;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri @remove-es;
    }

}
```

The media files are requested at their root without problem, but when the request comes from a subdirectory such as /es/ or /en/ there's the problem and I don't know how to rewrite since I started using nginx a few weeks ago and few days trying to implement subdirectories.

*Btw I'm still clueless to some things of Nginx so if you want to point another thing in my config that feels like a threat to humanity feel free to do so.*

Comment: Probably the better solution would be to fix it in the webpage. Where you are asking for an image like `src="./image.png"` use `src="/image.png"` instead.

Comment: I have tried this way and yeah it's easier and it works, but its changing too many things and in too many files, that's why I prefer to handle it directly at the server so I don't have to take this problem into the future. If it's possible, which I don't know tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a path-relative URI (one beginning with `./` or just missing a leading `/`), so the browser is adding the `/en/` or `/es/` prefix before sending it to the server. The preferred solution is to fix it in the webpage. Where you are asking for an image like `src="./image.png"` use `src="/image.png"` instead.

---

However, fixing Nginx to map `/es/image.png` and `/en/image.png` to the same file is relatively simple.

All URIs that begin with `/es/` and `/en/` are processed by their respective `location` blocks. Modify the `try_files` statements to rewrite the image URIs by removing the language prefix.

For example:

```
location ^~ /es/ {
    try_files $uri/.php $uri.php $uri/ @rewrite;
    ...
}

location ^~ /en/ {
    try_files $uri/.php $uri.php $uri/ @rewrite;
    ...
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(es|en)(/.*\.(png|jpg|svg|ico))$ $2 last;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote so I'll say it here even when the placeholder tells me not to. This is exactly the rewrite I needed, thank you.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem you can accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.